# android - widget surfaceview?

Tags: android, widget, surfaceview, flashlight

I'm programming a widget. When somebody clicks on the widget Button, the Flashlight is turning on. If you click again on the widget button, the Flashlight is turning off. I wrote a small app, there its works, because i have a surface view in my layout xml file. On my widget xml that is not working.

This is my widget_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/surface"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:src="@drawable/off"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

On the developer Page, there is a text:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

```
A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

FrameLayout
LinearLayout
RelativeLayout
GridLayout

And the following widget classes:

AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper
```

So my widget button will never work, because i can't use surface view.

Comment: How can i add Surface View in widget_layout.xml? So it works with the widget button.

Comment: user1205415, There is no way to make it. RemoteViews accept only a strictly defined set of Views. You gotta wait for future Android versions, hoping that the SurfaceView will get in this set once.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a dummy surface texture instead of a surface view.....for example:

Add this to turnLightOn code:

mCamera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));